# Generic Class Arguments in Java

Tags: java, android

So I'm passing Activities and Intents all over the place in my Android app to handle threading (I'm sure there is a better paradigm for this, as my code is starting to get annoyingly spaghetti-ish - usually a sign I'm not doing something right).

But anyways, I'm trying to do something like this:

```java
public class SomeCoolActivity extends Activity {
    private class DoSomeTaskThatInvolvesEitherTheNetworkOrASleepStatementWithoutScrewingUpTheUiThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Do something useful on a non-UI thread...
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Now that's done, I need to progress to the next activity. If I do that here,
            // I will get errors. So instead, I will call a method on my parent activity class:
            loadNextActivity(NextActivity.class);
        }
    }

    protected void loadNextActivity(Class<Activity> activityToLoad) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, activityToLoad));
    }
}
```

But this does not work, as it tells me there is an error, that

```
NextActivity.class
```

is not Activity. Yes, obviously it's not the exact same class, but one would expect me to be able to pass in ANY class that derives from Activity (including NextActivity), but not any class which does not (it does in fact work fine if I define loadNextActivity as

```
protected void loadNextActivity(Class<?> activityToLoad)
```

but that's less than ideal as then I could pass in anything I want, perhaps something which is not an Activity...this is Java, not Ruby, after all). And besides, if it only allows me to pass in exactly one class...what on earth good is it?

So how do I make this work?

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't really mis-spell onPostExecute() in your code; if you did, you should definitely look into that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write wildcard like:

```
protected void loadNextActivity(Class<? extends Activity> activityToLoad)
```

Its not good practice to use `Class<?>`. You won't know the exact type of the class token. Hmm, try to define global behavior for your method like I wrote above by using wildcard.

By the way be sure that each activity you add into the `Manifest.xml` file, like:

```
<activity android:name=".com.bla.bla.YourOtherActivity" />
```

Comment: Indeed - this works.

And yes - I definitely don't like using Class<?>.....unless I really want to be able to accept ANY class type, which I almost never want to do. Adding the extends Activity constraint works just fine.

As for the manifest, I generally let Eclipse do this by creating activity files with it. One less thing to worry about...

Answer (score 0):

Your code comments say "If I do that here, I will get errors.".  What errors are you getting?  Was it that you had an invalid context as an argument to getIntent()?  Or that startActivity() wasn't valid?  The likely reason was that onPostExecute() is being called from an inner class, not the Activity itself.

Try this:

```
  onPostExecute(Void result) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(SomeCoolActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
  }
```

Comment: I was getting a runtime error when I did that. I hadn't tracked it down, before I simply switched to calling calling a method outside of my fun async task sub-class, which I figured was just a threading mess. I will try it again, and see if I can get it to run like this, as, if I can, it makes for much less spaghetti-ishness, which, of course, blows.

Answer (score 0):

on a side note: you do not want to pass activities around and *never* want to save them in a variable. if you do that you leak the whole view hierarchy and will use up ram realy fast.

Comment: Agreed - though I'm not passing references to activity objects, just activity classes, which I'm then only using to start new instances of them.